# Ubuntu 20.04 keeps trying to login

Tags: 20.04, login-screen

When booting my laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 I get to the login screen, here I see my account as normal; after I click on my account it keeps submitting the unfilled password over and over again for several times resulting in the message: "sorry that didn't work please try again". (approximately 10 times or more)

After these 10 times submitting an empty password I can login without any problems and everything works fine until I log out again. When I try typing my password in this cycle I'm not fast enough and it submits the partial entered password resulting in the same message: "sorry that didn't work please try again".

It's really annoying to have to wait for this every time I wanne use my laptop. This problem appeared quite randomly from my perspective, and I have used Ubuntu 20.04 without any problems for quite a while before.

My laptop is a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon.

Comment: If you still have this problem: Does this happen if you boot from a live USB? (Try to boot into the Ubuntu 20.04.3 live USB, select Try Ubuntu Without Installing, create a new user with a password and logout to the user selection screen to test if it works.)

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem too. And I am the kind of person that like to lock screen at each time I leave my computer. The problem annoyed me very much.

I figured that the problem may be caused by fingerprint login. I wanted to use fingerprint to login so I set it and the problem came out. So I used the following command to remove fingerprint libraries:

```
$ sudo apt remove fprintd libfprint-2-2
```

And it works! I don't know if it will work on your computer or not, but have a try!